# For each 3 rows in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm retrieving data from MySQL which I'm listing on a page with HTML. I need each three throws from MySQL to be placed in a separate div when I'm looping through them.

My current code works but it prints all of the rows in a single div.

```
<div class="flex">
<?php 
    $get_plans = $database->sql("SELECT * FROM plans", array(), 'count');

    if ($get_plans != 0)
    {
        $get_plans = $database -> sql("SELECT * FROM plans", array(), 'rows');

        foreach ($get_plans as $plan)
        {
            $id = $plan['id'];
            $name = $plan['name'];

            echo '
                <div class="flex-33">
                    ID: '.$id.'
                    Name: '.$name.'
                </div>
            ';
        }
    }
?>
</div>
```

I would like the generated HTML to look like this: http://prntscr.com/ogx2bu

Comment: In your loop, increment a counter. When the counter gets to 3, start a new div and reset the counter.

Comment: Also, there's no need to run the SQL query twice, the value of `$get_plans` will still be intact inside the if.

Comment: @AlexHowansky, Thanks for the idea, trying it now. I'm using one to count and the other to retrieve information, that's why there is queries.

Comment: Try with [array_chunk()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

Comment: Ah, didn't notice that diff. Still, you can just run the second query by itself and use `!empty($get_plans)` in your conditional.

Comment: Noted that one in my mind. Thank you for your suggestions, appericated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use [`array_chunk()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php):

```
foreach (array_chunk($get_plans, 3) as $chunk) {
    echo '<div class="flex">';
    foreach ($chunk as $plan) {
        echo '<div class="flex-33">';
        echo 'ID: ' . $plan['id'] . '; ' . 'Name: ' . $plan['name'];
        echo '</div>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

The result will be like:

```
<div class="flex">
    <div class="flex-33">ID: ID1; Name: Name1</div>
    <div class="flex-33">ID: ID2; Name: Name2</div>
    <div class="flex-33">ID: ID3; Name: Name3</div>
</div>
<div class="flex">
    <div class="flex-33">ID: ID4; Name: Name4</div>
    <div class="flex-33">ID: ID5; Name: Name5</div>
    <div class="flex-33">ID: ID6; Name: Name6</div>
</div>
<div class="flex">
    <div class="flex-33">ID: ID7; Name: Name7</div>
</div>
```

See [demo on rextester.com](https://rextester.com/UWYV86706)

Comment: Visually this is a lot cleaner. However, I've always had an aversion to nested loops, as they tend to create performance issues. With smaller datasets, this is almost certainly a non-issue. But it is something to keep in mind.

Comment: @maiorano84 How would you traverse a nested array like a matrix?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel When an array comes back in that format, you pretty much don't have a choice. But that's not the case here since database queries aren't returned in a nested format, so I'm not sure what your question has to do with my point.

Comment: @maiorano84 You have a choice how to code a matrix. If you'd avoid nested loops at any price, you would code it in a linear array (like `[a1, b1, c1, a2, b2, c2]` instead of `[ [a1, b1, c1], [a2, b2, c2]]`). And while there can be reasons to do so in low level programming for "micro-optimization", it makes little to no sense for business logic and frontend programming, but just complicates the code. Also keep in mind that we all use "hidden" nested loops over all in our code, since many functions use loops internally. ...

Comment: ... The big question is the scale. And here it is number-of-chunks * size-of-chunk which is (N/3)*3 = N iterations - So it's linear to the data size. I though agree, that nested loops need a closer look. But it doesn't mean that anything is wrong using them. And a clear code makes it easier to verify, that everything is fine.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Aversion != Avoid at any price. Not sure where you came to that conclusion. There's a time and a place. So again, I'm not sure what you're commenting on here.

Comment: I am commenting on: "they tend to create performance issues". I could say that about almost anything in programming. But that doesn't stop me from programming :-) - Note: I don't even say that you are wrong. Just that we need to differentiate. And gain - I agree with "it is something to keep in mind".

Comment: Ok. Then let's look at my comment about nested loops: "They tend to create performance issues". There's nothing to differentiate here, because a "tendency" to create performance issues does not mean that it *will* create performance issues, or that the issues themselves are so bad that it warrants a refactor. **Keeping a close eye on potential pitfalls from nested loops has been my point from the start which you seem to have gotten**. But if we're both saying the same thing, what exactly are we discussing?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print your data in sets of 3 you can keep track of this using the index of your `$get_plans` array.

```
foreach($get_plans as $index => $plan) {
    $id = $plan['id'];
    $name = $plan['name'];
    $start_new_div = $index % 3 == 0; // Find if the current plan is 1st,4th, 7th...
    if ($start_new_div) {
        echo '<div class="flex">';
    }
    echo '
        <div class="flex-33">
            ID: '.$id.'
            Name: '.$name.'
        </div>
    ';
    $close_current_div = $index % 3 == 2 || $index == count($get_plans) - 1; // If the current plan is 3rd, 6th, 9th... or is the last plan in array
    if ($close_current_div) {
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

Another option is to loop over the `$get_plans` array and construct your string with data from sets of 3 and insert the string into another array.
Then loop over this new array and print your string into a div as you wish.

Edit: Updated code to match the added screenshot of the desired output.